# How to extend React.JS CommentBox example to allow deleting of comments?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to extend the [React.JS CommentBox example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) to include the ability to delete comments.  I have added a simple button to the `Comment` class and all of the necessary methods and listeners.  Now I am trying to add functionality to a `handleDelete` method in my `CommentBox` class to do the necessary Ajax calls to delete the comment on server as well as locally

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    // Optimistically set an id on the new comment. It will be replaced by an
    // id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
    // not use Date.now() for this and would have a more robust system in place.
    comment.id = Date.now();
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});

    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: comments});
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  handleDelete: function(id) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    var newComments = [];
    var commentToDelete = null;

    for (var i = 0, len = comments.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (comments[i].id != id) {
            newComments.push(comments[i]);
        } else {
            commentToDelete = comments[i];
        }
    }

    this.setState({data: newComments});

    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: commentToDelete,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: comments});
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.

        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} onCommentDelete={this.handleDelete} />
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  handleDelete: function(id) {
    console.log('handleDelete2 ' + id);
    this.props.onCommentDelete(id);
  },
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
      var handle_delete = this.handleDelete.bind(this, comment.id);

      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id} onCommentDelete={handle_delete}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    }, this);
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {author: '', text: ''};
  },
  handleAuthorChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
  },
  handleTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = this.state.author.trim();
    var text = this.state.text.trim();
    if (!text || !author) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
    this.setState({author: '', text: ''});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Your name" 
            value={this.state.author} 
            onChange={this.handleAuthorChange} 
        />
        <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Say something..." 
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleTextChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup: function() {
    var md = new Remarkable();
    var rawMarkup = md.render(this.props.children.toString());
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  },

  handleDelete: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleDelete");
    this.props.onCommentDelete();
  },

  render: function() {
    var md = new Remarkable();
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
        <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox url="/api/comments" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

However, the item won't delete permanently and there is an error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
/api/comments error Method Not Allowed
```

I really am not an Ajax expert so I am sure I am making a very obvious mistake.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you received the server side error message, you need to add the delete functionality to server side also. Or share the implemented delete server side code.

Comment: Ya looks like delete is not implemented in the backend or you're calling it wrong.

Comment: I am using the server which was preconfigured for the tutorial.  So I guess I would have to open that preconfigured code and add functionality to that?